# NoReverseMatch Error in django while creating shopping cart app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Getting error NoReverseMatch

```
Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/']
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cart/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

views.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
request.session.set_expiry(120000)

try:
    the_id = request.session['cart_id']
except:
    new_cart = Cart()
    new_cart.save()
    request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
    the_id = new_cart.id

cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

try:
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    pass
except:
    pass

product_var = [] #product variation
if request.method == "POST":
    qty = request.POST['qty']
    for item in request.POST:
        key = item
        val = request.POST[key]
        try:
            v = Variation.objects.get(product=product, category__iexact=key, title__iexact=val)
            product_var.append(v)
        except:
            pass
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)
    if len(product_var) > 0:
        cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
    cart_item.quantity = qty
    cart_item.save()
    # success message
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
#error message
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

prod.html

```
<form class='form' method='POST' action='{% url "add_to_cart" product.slug %}'> {% csrf_token %}
             <input class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='submit' value='Add to cart'/>
            <input  class="form-control"  name='qty' type='number' value='1'/>

            {% if product.variation_set.all %}


            {% if product.variation_set.sizes %}
            <select class='form-control' name='size'>
            {% for item in product.variation_set.sizes %}
                <option value='{{ item.title|lower }}'>{{ item.title|capfirst }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

             {% if product.variation_set.colors %}
            <select class='form-control' name='color'>
            {% for item in product.variation_set.colors %}
                <option value='{{ item.title|lower }}'>{{ item.title|capfirst }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% endif %}



            {% endif %}

         </form>
```

I think i am missing something. Even if I mention other url name it displays the same error with that url pattern. Do i have to import something which can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the view responsible for rendering `prod.html` in the first place. But it is clear from the error that the object you are passing as `product` to that template has an empty string for its `slug` attribute.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Danieal

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing you are not providing, a required argument which is the slug, and 'cart' is supposed to be a string. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/

```
url = reverse('cart', args=(slug,))
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```